# How to count the number of times a constructor is called?

Tags: matlab, class, oop, constructor

I have this Python code here below. Below that is my attempt at converting it to MATLAB code. I'm new to `classdef`, and I'm doing the conversion for practice. The problem with `counter` (want to compute  the number of times I called a constructor)  and I would appreciate feedback on how to correct my conversion.

The Python version:

```py
 class Test:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        Test.counter += 1
```

My attempt at a MATLAB conversion:

```matlab
classdef Test
    properties
        counter=0;
        id;
    end
    methods
        function self= Test(id)
            self.id = id;
            self.counter = self.counter+1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The constructor is always called exactly once for each object. Does `counter` in the Python code actually ever have a value that is not 1?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution

```matlab
classdef Test
    properties
        id;
    end
    methods
        function self= Test(id)
            self.id = id;
        end
    end
    methods (Static)
        function c= counter
            persistent Count;
            if isempty(Count)
                Count = 1;
            else
                Count = Count + 1;
            end
            c = Count;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Persistent variables should generally be avoided, and I'm not sure what the use case is here - how do you imagine calling this static method? What if it's called from external code (since it's a public method) and the counter changes? In your solution, the `counter` function isn't even called so I'm not sure how it helps..

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but indeed the constructor is still not counting, and I guess you might need to retrieve the count without increasing the count?

Comment: @wolfie: why do you say that persistent variables should generally be avoided? They’re very useful indeed, not at all like global variables.

Comment: @Wolfie : `a=Test(5)` ..... `b=Test(8)` .  In this case **a.counter==1** and **b.counter==2**.

Comment: @CrisLuengo : No, it's counting. I've tested it.

Comment: `a.counter` returns 1, then 2, then 3, then 4,... every time you cal it, it adds one to the internal counter. The function is not called by the constructor, so calling the constructor does not increase the counter. You need to add a value to the class, and set this value to the current counter in the constructor.

Comment: @Wolfie: Well, there are lots of questions on here from people misunderstanding basic for loops in MATLAB, I don’t think that’s a reason to avoid them.

Comment: @Wolfie : As you said, it's  personal preference. Thank you guys for your responses.

Comment: @Wolfie : Could you post your solution, I'm beginner in **classdef**

Comment: @Zak I can't, because I don't think your question is clear enough to prompt a solution - it's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve